# Installing php53-devel on an Amazon Suse

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, opensuse, zypper

*(I hope this is the right place for this type of question)*

I'm trying to install cURL on a *SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 sp3* machine. I'm using this action to do so:

> sudo zypper install php53-devel

And I get this error message:

> Refreshing service 'susecloud'. Problem retrieving the repository index file for service 'susecloud': Download (curl) error for 'http://default-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/repoindex.xml?cookies=0': Error code: Unrecognized error Error message: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>
> Check if the URI is valid and accessible. Retrieving repository 'SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool' metadata [] Download (curl) error for 'http://default-ec2-update.susecloud.net/repo/update/SLE11-SDK-SP3-Pool/sle-11-x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml': Error code: Unrecognized error Error message: SSL certificate problem, verify that the CA cert is OK. Details: error:14090086:SSL routines:SSL3_GET_SERVER_CERTIFICATE:certificate verify failed
>
> Abort, retry, ignore? [a/r/i/? shows all options]

I have very little understanding on this kind of stuff and I don't know what command should I use to update (or install?) a *CA cert*. I don't know where are my certificates and how do I update them.

If you can help me with this or guide me to a solution, that would be great.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears there's a problem with SUSE on AWS the past few days.

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=559135

> Apparently the DigiCert High Assurance EV Root CA cert has expired this afternoon.

This appears to affect other systems as well. https://blog.digicert.com/expired-intermediate-certificate/ https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=8094072

Comment: So it's only a matter of time?

Comment: @Amitay Presumably. The thread says it has been resolved now, give it a shot.

Comment: I just did, and it is fixed, now I need to understand how to install the curl, because now it tells me that it can't find the php53-devel package :\

Comment: I've opened a new question about it here - http://serverfault.com/questions/616316/install-curl-on-an-amazon-suse