# install cURL on an Amazon Suse

Tags: amazon-web-services, curl, zypper

I'm trying to install cURL on a *SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 sp3* machine. I'm using this action to do so:

```
sudo zypper in curl
```

And I get this error message:

```
Refreshing service 'susecloud'.
Loading repository data...
Reading installed packages...
'curl' is already installed.
Package 'curl' is not available in your repositories. Cannot reinstall, upgrade, or downgrade.
Resolving package dependencies...
Nothing to do.
```

I have very little understanding on this kind of stuff and I don't know what command should I use to update (or install?) the cURL.
When using *phpinfo* I can't see any cURL enabled.

If you can help me with this or guide me to a solution, that would be great.

Edit:

*extension=php_curl.dll* and *extension=curl.so* are enabled on the *php.ini*.

Comment: Install PHP support for curl, usually in a package name that has both PHP and curl in it, like php5-curl.

Comment: @Brian I've tried `sudo zypper install php5-curl` but I get this message: _'php5-curl' not found in package names. Trying capabilities. No provider of 'php5-curl' found._

Comment: That should have worked, update the local cache for the repositories with `zypper up` then try again.

Comment: nope...still the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [SOLVED]

What I did to solve this issue was to launch a different machine.

I has: *SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 sp3 (HVM), SSD Volume Type*

I now have: *SuSE Linux Enterprise Server 11 sp3 (PV), SSD Volume Type*

On the new machine I did as the following:

1. Open a new dir (in etc) and call it “curl”
2. Go to it: cd /etc/curl
3. Run *wget https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.25.tar.gz/from/il1.php.net/mirror*
   (From here: https://www.php.net/get/php-5.4.25.tar.gz/from/a/mirror)
   if you can’t find the file, change the version to the latest php version (find it on php.net)
4. Unzip it: *tar xfz php-5.4.25.tar.gz*
5. Enter the new directory that was just created and than to ext/curl
   cd php-X.X.XX/ext/curl
6. *sudo zypper install php53-devel*
7. *sudo zypper install libcurl-devel*
8. *sudo zypper install gcc*
9. *phpize*
10. *./configure*
11. *make*
12. *sudo make install*
    (check all that you’ve done with php -i|grep -i curl)
13. Go to the PHP.INI and make sure the line *extension=curl.so* is there and uncommented.
14. Restart the apache

That's it. I hope this will help somebody in the future :)